# How can I read a c3d file on Python?

Tags: python, pandas, windows, installation, jsc3d

I'm trying to read a c3d file on Python with the btk library but I didn't succeed.
I downloaded the library here https://code.google.com/archive/p/b-tk/downloads for Windows 10 (64 bit) and then wrote this code:

[image: Error of my code]

Comment: You have to actually fill in the path to the library in line 2. And don't post images of code/errors, insert them as code blocks.

Comment: I filled the path to the library but it still doesn't work. When I try to open the library on Jupyter I have the following error : Error! C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda-3\site-packages\btk\btk.pyd is not UF-8 encoded. Saving disabled.   Do you think this could be problem ? If it is the case, do you know how to solve it ?

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Sorry, being a beginner on stack overflow I didn't know how to insert the code. Here is my code :

Comment: ```import sys
```sys.path.append(r"C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\btk\__init__.py")
```#print(sys.path)
```import btk
```reader = btk.btkAcquisitionFileReader()```

Answer (score 0):

try https://pypi.org/project/c3d/

or https://github.com/pyomeca/pyomeca

its easier with them than with btk toolkit. You will need to see docs to get it done. I am using those to read only, then switch to numpy or pandas.